# Wordpress - Show all child categories associated to post ID within loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm looping through all posts and I'm trying to output the category nicename related to each post. So if there are categories A,B and C with post X only associated with categories A and C then I only want to output category A and C's nicename.

Here's the loop:

```
<?php $subs = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'case-study' ));
  if( $subs->have_posts() ) : while( $subs->have_posts() ) : $subs->the_post(); ?>

  <?php the_title(); ?>

  <p>Associated Child Categories</p>
  //Show nicenames of each child category associated to each post
  <?php $category = get_categories($post->ID);
        foreach(($category) as $cats) { echo $category->category_nicename; }?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [get_the_category()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) would be ideal for this situation, since you're doing this within The Loop:

```
$post_cats = get_the_category();
if ( $post_cats ) {
    foreach ( $post_cats as $cat ) {
        // Only show child categories (exclude parents)
        if ( ! $cat->category_parent === '0' ) {
            echo $cat->cat_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is great although its outputting the parent category as well as children. How can I exclude the parent?